# Setting Attribute Value Depending on User Select Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, simple-form

On my create new article page, I have a select drop down for different options. Depending on what option the user chooses, I would like to set the value of another attribute.

Having trouble finding the best way to do this. Would I write an if statement inside of the new view? Or article controller?

here is my new.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label "Rating" %><br>
<%= f.select :rating, options_for_select(['A+','A','A-','B+','B','B-','C+','C','C-','D+','D','D-','F+','F','F-'], params[:rating]), {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>

<%= f.label "Rating color" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :ratingcolor %>
```

Specifically, when a user selects an A+, A, or A-, I would like the :ratingcolor to automatically be assigned the color green. If B+, B, or B-, then the color yellow... and so on..

If there is already documentation on this, can you please point me that way? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

new.html.erb (a simplified version)

```
<div class="form-inputs">

  <%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <select id="rating">
    <option value="A+">A+</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="A-">A-</option>
    <option value="B+">B+</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="B-">B-</option>
    <option value="C+">C+</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C-">C-</option>
  </select>
  <label for="rating_color">Rating color</label>
  <input id="rating_color" type="text" name="rating_color" />

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Since I am using simple_form_for, I tried something like this

```
<%= f.label "Rating" %><br>
<%= f.select :rating, options_for_select(['A+','A','A-','B+','B','B-','C+','C','C-','D+','D','D-','F+','F','F-'], params[:rating]), {}, :class => 'span3 controls controls-row', :input_html => { :id => "rating" } %>

<%= f.label "Rating color" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :ratingcolor, input_html => { :id => "rating_color" } %>
```

But this did not work.

Here is my articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @articles = Article.search(params[:query], misspellings: {edit_distance: 1})
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end

    if @articles.blank?
      return redirect_to request_path
    end

    get_query
  end

  def show
     @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   if request.path != article_path(@article)
      redirect_to @article, status: :moved_permanently
    else
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @article }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @article = current_user.articles.new
  end

  def edit
     @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
     respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:isare, :name, :image1, :image2, :image3, :image4, :r1image, :r2image, :r3image, :r4image, :title, :aka, :category, :rating, :ratingcolor, :whyrating, :alternative1, :alternative2, :alternative3, :checkthisout, :nutritiontable, :sugarsdp, :facts, :video1, :video2, :related1, :related2, :related3, :related4, :sources)
    end

    def get_query
      @userquery = params[:query]
    end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like `Javascript`.  Have you tried to do this with `jQuery`?  Also, do you mean you want `:ratingcolor` to be assigned the string "green", "yellow", etc?

Comment: yes exactly, it would be a string. Is javascript the best way to to do this?

Comment: Yes I would write this in `jQuery`.  Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not, going to have to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2khdtnxq/9/).  Basically, get the value from the `select` and then use it to set the value in the `text field`.  Note that I have used `id=rating` and `id=rating_color` as the hooks but you can change these as you see fit (they just need to match between the `HTML` and `JavaScript`.

This can all go together in your view or you can put the JS in a separate file in `app/assets/javascripts` (better).  Just make sure you are including `jQuery` in your manifest file (I think it is by default in Rails 4+).

Comment: Can't thank you enough man. One question, how do I get the :rating and :ratingcolor attributes in there? When I submit the form, the values aren't saving.. so in the view page nothing shows. Getting close though!

Comment: Do you mean back at your controller?  In your view, do you use a helper like `form_for` and then submit at the end?  Maybe you can update your post with your whole view (or at least the form), plus your controller code.

Comment: One minute, will update. Yes simple_form_for with a submit at the end